# PSE of card not what it is supposed to be

Tags: java, smartcard, contactless-smartcard, emv

So, I have a contactless Mastercard and a Visa paywave phone.
I use a contactless HID Omnikey 5427 CK.

This is my code: `

```
static boolean cardReading = true;

public static void main(String[] args) throws CardException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    while (cardReading == true) {

    try {
    TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
    List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();
    CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);

    if (!terminal.isCardPresent()) {

        continue;

    }

    System.out.println("Terminals: " + terminals);
    System.out.println("Used terminal: " + terminal);

    Card card = terminal.connect("T=0");
    System.out.println("\n\nInserted card: " + card);
    CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();

    String pse = "00A404000E325041592E5359532E444446303100";
    CommandAPDU apdu = new CommandAPDU(pse.getBytes());
    ResponseAPDU r = channel.transmit(apdu);

    System.out.println("Response: " + toHex(r.getData().toString()) + " " + r);
    System.out.println("ADPU: " + toHex(apdu.getBytes().toString()) + " " + r.getSW() + " " + r.getSW1() + " " + r.getSW2() + " " + r.getNr());

    apdu = new CommandAPDU((byte)0x00, (byte)0xB2, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x0C, (byte)0x00);
    r = channel.transmit(apdu);

    cardReading = false;
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();

    System.out.println("Terminals: " + terminals);
    System.out.println("Used terminal: " + terminal);
    System.out.println("\n\nInserted card: " + card);
    System.out.println("Response: " + toHex(r.getData().toString()) + " " + r);
    System.out.println("ADPU: " + toHex(apdu.getBytes().toString()) + " " + r.getSW() + " " + r.getSW1() + " " + r.getSW2() + " " + r.getNr());



    System.exit(1);

    } catch(Exception e) {

        continue;

    }

    }

}

public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                             + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}

public static String toHex(String arg) {
    return String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes()));
}
```

`

And so the output is:

```
Terminals: [PC/SC terminal HID OMNIKEY 5427 CK 0]
Used terminal: PC/SC terminal HID OMNIKEY 5427 CK 0


Inserted card: PC/SC card in HID OMNIKEY 5427 CK 0, protocol T=0, state OK
Response: 0000000000000000005b42403163343630306630 ResponseAPDU: 65 bytes, SW=9000
ADPU: 000000000000000000005b424035623665663230 36864 144 0 63
Terminals: [PC/SC terminal HID OMNIKEY 5427 CK 0]
Used terminal: PC/SC terminal HID OMNIKEY 5427 CK 0


Inserted card: PC/SC card in HID OMNIKEY 5427 CK 0, protocol T=0, state OK
Response: 0000000000000000005b42403565616235383039 ResponseAPDU: 14 bytes, SW=9000
ADPU: 0000000000000000005b42403433323065373664 36864 144 0 12
```

I do not understand why is the response 0000000000000000005b42403565616235383039...
Please help.

Regards, Vlad.

Comment: What response are you expecting? What is not working? Please clarify.

Comment: @JimGarrison People usually get something like this in response: 6F2F840E325041592E5359532E4444463031A51DBF0C1A61184F07A0000000031010500A564953412044454249548701019000

Comment: It includes the AID or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a byte array to a hex string in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java)

Comment: The problem is that you are not properly converting the command/response APDUs into a hexadecimal string representation. In your current code, you use the `.toString()` method of the byte arrays. This method does **not** return a string representation of the byte array. Instead it only returns a reference/hash code that won't reveal any information about the actual data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Michael Roland says -- your handling of hexadecimal strings is wrong.

**Meta-mistake 1: Using 'byte[].toString()'**

```
r.getData().toString()
```

The `byte[].toString` uses the default `Object.toString()` implementation which returns the class name followed by `@` and the value of `Object.hashCode()` (e.g. `"[B@312b1dae"`) -- which is not what you want for further processing.

You can use the `Arrays.toString()` method (which does not do the hexadecimal dump), or [any other method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9655181/5128464).

**Meta-mistake 2: Using 'String.getBytes()'**

```
String pse = "00A404000E325041592E5359532E444446303100";
CommandAPDU apdu = new CommandAPDU(pse.getBytes());
```

Does not create the desired APDU object as the method `String.getBytes()` does not perform hexadecimal conversion, but a charset conversion in the platform's default charset, e.g.: `"1234".getBytes()` gives `{ 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34 }` (and not `{ 0x12, 0x34 }` as you might expect).

Below is a simple code example which performs (almost) the same as your code:

```
package test.java.so;

import java.util.List;

import javax.smartcardio.Card;
import javax.smartcardio.CardChannel;
import javax.smartcardio.CardTerminal;
import javax.smartcardio.CommandAPDU;
import javax.smartcardio.ResponseAPDU;
import javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class So39543402 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
                List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();
                CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);

                Card card = terminal.connect("*");
                CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();

                String pse = "00A404000E325041592E5359532E444446303100";
                CommandAPDU apdu = new CommandAPDU(Hex.decodeHex(pse.toCharArray()));
                exchangeApdu(channel, apdu);

                apdu = new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0xB2, 0x01, 0x0C, 256);
                exchangeApdu(channel, apdu);
    }

    private static ResponseAPDU exchangeApdu(CardChannel channel, CommandAPDU apdu) throws javax.smartcardio.CardException {
        System.out.println("APDU: " + Hex.encodeHexString(apdu.getBytes()));
        ResponseAPDU r = channel.transmit(apdu);
        System.out.println("Response: " + Hex.encodeHexString(r.getBytes()));
        return r;
    }

}
```

Please note some interesting parts:

- this code uses [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) for the hexadecimal conversions
- argument `"*"` is used for `CardTerminal.connect()` which is more versatile than always requesting the `T=0` protocol
- your `READ RECORD` APDU was modified to expect 256 bytes of response data -- [this is how this particular constructor works](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/CommandAPDU.html#CommandAPDU(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) (your code would produce an ISO case 1 Command-APDU which is probably not what you want)

One additional note:

- do not use the `String.getBytes()` method without parameters (even when you do want to convert single characters into bytes). Always specify the desired character set (e.g. "US-ASCII", "UTF-8")

Good luck!